# Is it possible to create a vector with references to lazy-static values?

Tags: vector, static, rust

The following code compiles:

```
let x = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
let y = Regex::new(r"asdf\d+").unwrap();
let regexes = vec![x, y];
```

But this code does not:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref X_PRIME: Regex = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
    static ref Y_PRIME: Regex = Regex::new(r"asdf\d+").unwrap();
}
let regexes = vec![X_PRIME, Y_PRIME];
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\syntax\lex.rs:19:33
   |
19 |     let regexes = vec![X_PRIME, Y_PRIME];
   |                                 ^^^^^^^ expected struct `syntax::lex::lex::X_PRIME`, found struct `syntax::lex::lex::Y_PRIME`
   |
   = note: expected type `syntax::lex::lex::X_PRIME`
   = note:    found type `syntax::lex::lex::Y_PRIME`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. lazy_static gives `X_PRIME` and `Y_PRIME` distinct types, but they both [implement `Deref<Regex>`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/0.2.2/lazy_static/#semantic), so you could write:

```
let regexes = vec![&*X_PRIME, &*Y_PRIME];
// The * dereferences the values to a `Regex` type
// The & turn them back into references `&Regex`.
```

You could also just define another static:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref X_PRIME: Regex = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
    static ref Y_PRIME: Regex = Regex::new(r"asdf\d+").unwrap();
    static ref REGEXES: Vec<&'static Regex> = vec![&X_PRIME, &Y_PRIME];
}
```